# Plupload response with whole html document

Tags: javascript, php, html, plupload

I am new with plupluad. I made one nice uploader but it doesn't work when I copied to another page. It's using same php file for upload. I was inspecting 'network' in chrome and my **plupload.php** said `done` but in response there is whole html document, and image was not uploaded. First I don't have idea how to debug it...

Here is my html code:

```
<?php
 require_once '../../core/init.inc.php';
 require_once $admin_header_path;
?>

 <script src="<?php echo $site_admin_url; ?>assets/libs/plupload/plupload.full.min.js"></script>

 <h1>Edit Gallery:</h1>

 <?php
  $galeries = new Galery();

 if(isset($_GET['slug'])) {
   $results = $galeries->get($_GET['slug']);
   $result = $results[0];
?>
<div id="errors">

</div>

<div class="loadingmessage" id="loadingmessage">
    <h1 style="color: red">WAIT...</h1>
</div>

<a id="upload_more" href="#">Upload more</a>

<div id="dialog_edit" class="dialog">
    <b><a style="float: right" id="more_close" href="#">X</a></b>
    <input id="upload_slug" type="hidden" name="slug" value="<?php echo $_GET['slug'] ?>"/>

    <h2 style="text-align: center">Images:</h2>

    <div id="upload">
        <div id="plupload">

            <div id="droparea">
                <p>Drop files</p>
                <span class="or">or</span>
                <a id="browse" href="#">[Select images]</a>
            </div>
            <a style="border:3px solid red;padding: 3px;" href="#" id="done">DONE</a>
            <div id="filelist">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="<?php echo $site_admin_url; ?>galeries/js/plupload.js"></script>

<?php
 } else {
  } ?>
```

Here is my JS plupload.js file:

```
var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
   runtimes : 'html5, flash',
   containes: 'plupload',
   browse_button: 'browse',
   drop_element: "droparea",
   url : '../plupload.php',
   flash_swf_url : 'admin/assets/plupload/Moxie.swf',
   silverlight_xap_url : 'admin/assets/plupload/Moxie.xap',
   multipart: true,
   urlstream_upload: true,
   multipart_params: {
    "slug" : $("#upload_slug").val() // HERE I AM SENDING slug TO PHP
   },
   max_file_size : '5mb',
   resize : {width:800, height:600, quality: 90},
  filters : [
    {title:'Images', extensions : 'jpg,jpeg,gif,png'}
  ]
});

 uploader.bind('UploadProgress', function(up, file) {
   $("#" + file.id).find('.progress').css('width',file.percent + '%');
});

uploader.init();

uploader.bind('FilesAdded', function(up, files) {
   var filelist = $("#filelist");
  plupload.each(files, function(file) {
    filelist.prepend('<div class="file" id="' + file.id + '">' + file.name + ' (' + plupload.formatSize(file.size) + ') <div class="progressbar"><div class="progress"></div></div></div>');
   });
  $("#droparea").removeClass('hover');
  uploader.start();
  uploader.refresh();
});

uploader.bind("FileUploaded", function(up, file, response) {
  $('#' + file.id).find('.progressbar').fadeOut();
});

uploader.bind('Error', function(up, err){
  alert("\nError #" + err.code + ": " + err.message);
  uploader.refresh();
});
```

And my plupload.php:

```
<?php

 require_once '../../core/init.inc.php';
 $db = DB::getInstance();
 $slug = "none";

 if(!isset($_POST['slug'])) {
     $query = $db->getPDO()->prepare("SELECT slug FROM pd_galeries ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
    $query->execute();
    $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $slug = $result[0]->slug;
 } else {
    $slug = $_POST['slug'];
 }

  $upload = new Upload("gallery", $_FILES['file'], $slug);
  $upload->upload();
```

Method `upload()` works, I know because it works on antoher page...

[image]